# "Node is empty" warning displayed in Google Structured Data Testing Tool

Tags: wordpress, structured-data, site-structure

With the latest version of the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), I got 5 warning messages saying:

> Node is empty. Double check that this is desired and consider
>   removing.

How can I remove this warning?

I searched for help on this topic, but could not find a reliable answer.

Here is a screenshot of the HTML code and warning:

[image: google structural data test warning for aiocheats.com]

Comment: Please include the markup in your question *as text* (in [code blocks](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code)), and ideally remove anything that is not related to this error.